# Windows 8 app rejected due to Privacy Policy

Tags: windows-8

I am new to Windows 8 app development, I was working on a web Api but my app for rejected for not containing Privacy Policy. How to add it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the privacy policy under the Settings Charms of windows 8 app, Which can be achieved my pressing Windows + C Key .
Rest you need to make a blog/ Website that targets you to the Privacy policy page.
Copy and paste the code below

http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Default.aspx?tabid=67&EntryID=228

For a sample privacy policy visit

http://apoorvkupadhyay.blogspot.in

Comment: Correct answer. +1 for that. But I think creating a app related website and writing the statement there will be more good.

Comment: What I Did , created a blog and that costs me nothing

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a web page with the text of your private policy. Something like "The application insert-name does not collect any information about you" is enough. Once you have the url, you can add inside the settings charm the private "section":

```
SettingsCommand privacy = new SettingsCommand("privacy", "Privacy Policy", (uiCommand) => { ShowSettingsPanel(); });
args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(privacy);
```

Then, in the function ShowSettingsPanel (for example), just open the browser:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://colorchallenge.co.nf/privacy_policy.html"));
```

Remember that you need to tell the program that you want to add that to the settings section. To do so, if MyApp_CommandsRequested is the name of the function where you have the code at the beginning, you have to do this:

```
SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += MyApp_CommandsRequested;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

[PricacyStatementJavascript](http://codesquire.com/blog/PrivacyStatementJavascript/)

Comment: welcome & thanks for input. this however is not a full, self-contained answer. linked pages tend to move or become outdated and for that reason an answer like yours should be posted in a comment to the original question. please expand your answer including the steps necessary to resolve the issue.